# Here Map iOS Premium SDK, map not loading

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I am trying to running the SwiftHelloMap project with my 90-day Evaluation account.

But I got some error with the premium iOS SDK:

2018-01-30 09:45:42.533459+0800 SwiftHelloMap[98935:4357078] Task <2A3E17D1-6D61-433F-A5DB-3FE044BEE3F2>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
2018-01-30 09:45:42.755166+0800 SwiftHelloMap[98935:4357047] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2018-01-30 09:45:42.755280+0800 SwiftHelloMap[98935:4357047] Task .<2> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])

And the starter demo work fine.

That’s so strange, I have entered my app id, app code and license key; also change the Bundle ID to myself ID.

Should I do more steps when using the premium SDK?

I also tried the info.plist settings:
NSAppTransportSecurity  NSAllowsArbitraryLoads  
The log change to: 
HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89]) 
finished with error - code: -999

Comment: Did you check App Transport Security? try adding `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>` in your `info.plist`.

Comment: The default settings is
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>here.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
and with your settings, the error change to
Task <08913090-BF88-4BE5-8195-938A5D757B03>.<2> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
Task <08913090-BF88-4BE5-8195-938A5D757B03>.<2> finished with error - code: -999

Answer (score 0):

Our iOS premium has so many new updates and your issue is no longer reproducible.

Please check the documentation and the many code examples at:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing.html

https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples